# Combine nested dict items to a string

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have below nested dict `d`:

```py
{
 1: {1: {'text': 'Contact', 'x0': Decimal('21.600')}},
 2: {1: {'text': 'My mail is', 'x0': Decimal('21.600')},
     2: {'text': 'domain@example.com', 'x0': Decimal('223.560')}}
}
```

I am trying to "combine" the nested dictionaries for each top-level key into a string (that should form a sentence). For example:

```
1: Contact
2: My mail is domain@example.com
```

So I am a bit in doubt on how to do this in Python. This is what I have currently:

```py
for line in d:
    for word_no, text in d[line].items():
        print(text['text'])
```

This prints each `text` string, but doesn't combine anything. Can anyone guide me in the right direction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need another iteration.

**Ex:**

```
from decimal import Decimal

d = {
 1: {1: {'text': 'Contact', 'x0': Decimal('21.600')}},
 2: {1: {'text': 'My mail is', 'x0': Decimal('21.600')},
     2: {'text': 'domain@example.com', 'x0': Decimal('223.560')}}
}

for k, v in d.items():
    print("{}: {}".format(k, " ".join(n["text"] for _, n in v.items())))   #Combine "text"
```

**Output:**

```
1: Contact
2: My mail is domain@example.com
```

Comment: This works perfectly! I am trying to learn Python - do you mind explaining (very brief), what is happening at `for _, n in [...]` is this an inline loop?

Comment: I am just doing a regular iteration on a `dict`. I used `_` for key because it is not used anyplace.

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
>>> from decimal import Decimal

>>> d = {
 1: {1: {'text': 'Contact', 'x0': Decimal('21.600')}},
 2: {1: {'text': 'My mail is', 'x0': Decimal('21.600')},
     2: {'text': 'domain@example.com', 'x0': Decimal('223.560')}}
}

>>> for k,v in d.items():
    s = ""
    for ik,iv in v.items():
        s+=" "+iv['text']
    print("{}: {}".format(k,s))
```

---

**Output:**

```
1:  Contact
2:  My mail is domain@example.com
```

Answer (score 0):

The key and value pairs in dictionary are not in any particular order.
If ordering of your sentences / words is significant, you must sort dict values by keys (using [sorted()](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/functions.html#sorted)).
To concatenate string use [str.join()](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.join) function with list of substrings as argument.

This is simplified version using list concatenation:

```
for i in sorted(d.keys()):
    print '%s: %s' % (i, ' '.join([d[i][u]['text'] for u in sorted(d[i].keys())]))
```

And this is more verbose version:

```
for i in sorted(d.keys()):
    texts = []
    for u in sorted(d[i].keys()):
        texts.append(d[i][u]['text'])
    print '%s: %s' % (i, ' '.join(texts))
```

Comment: Good point! If the dict is already sorted, before being iterated in the above loop, do I need to sort it again?

Comment: There is no guarantee that a result will be correct without sorting. You may end up with the result "domain@example.com My mail is". 
I don't know, if I am getting Your question correctly.
First iteration is sorting "main" dictionary and nested sorting is sorting sub-dictionary.
You can not create sorted dictionary before processing.